Issue with New Tab Not Gaining Focus in Safari on iPhone
I'm experiencing an issue where a new tab doesn't gain focus when opened in Safari on iPhone...
When I open a new window using window.open, the focus shifts to the newly opened window as expected. However, I have a requirement to ensure that only one tab is open at a time, so I'm assigning a name value when calling window.open.
The problem arises when I try to reuse the same name to open a new tab while keeping the previous tab intact. In Safari on iPhone, the new tab doesn't get focus. It works fine in other browsers, but in Safari, even though the previous tab is overwritten with the new URL, the focus doesn't switch to the new tab. :confused:
This issue only occurs on Safari for iPhone; all other browsers work as expected. :crying_face:
Additional info: To bypass Safari's popup blocking policy, we're using a shared utility function like this:
const openNewTab = (url: string, name: WindowName = WindowName.NewTab) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.open(url, name);
  }, 0);
};

Has anyone experienced this issue or have any troubleshooting suggestions? Here's what I've tried so far:

Executing a focus event right after window.open – failed

Using the return value from window.open and calling focus on it – failed

Adding a setTimeout before calling focus on the window.open return value – failed



This question is similar to: $window.focus() doesn't work on existing tabs in iOS Safari. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question seems to address the same issue I’m experiencing. However, the answers provided are not helpful in my case. They mainly suggest that this is just an iOS issue and provide non-working code examples. Additionally, the post is over four years old, so it may not reflect the current state of iOS or Safari. I'm looking for a more up-to-date solution
